# How change foundation's button to always be enabled?

Tags: button, zurb-foundation

Which class I need to add, or to do something else, on my button to look still enabled after click?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be advised that StackOverflow is not a "write my code" service. If you are in need of help, please post the code you have written so we may assist you appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I have understood the question correctly, but:

You will need to target the buttons `:active` or `:focus` pseudo selector and set the background colour to the same as the button background colour.

So something like (in SCSS):

```
.button{
  &:active,&:focus{
    background: $primary-color;
  }
}
```

So that when you click the button or it's activated, it'll still be the same colour as the initial state.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i needed.